# Liferay exception on user creation com.liferay.portal.GroupFriendlyURLException

Tags: java, liferay, programmatically-created

I created an user whit XXX username from java code.

Because it was done with wrong permission and I can't see it from web interface, I delete directly from database.

After that if I try to create the same user I got the following exeception:

```
 com.liferay.portal.GroupFriendlyURLException
```

What could gone wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some investigation I discover that:

1. Store user info in USER_ table
2. For each USER_ row there are a row in GROUP_ table, where personal sites url are
3. On user cration Liferay use username to generate a friendly url
4. this url have to be validated, and one rule is that must be unique

My problem was that I deleted the USER_ row only, so whe I tried to recreate deleted user control on GROUP_ table failed.

So I solved with:

- GROUP_ row deletion (the one whit / on friendly url column)
- Liferay restart